# How to implement searching in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, search, mobile

In my app I have the search bar and screen with some static text on it. How can I display search results and when you click on one of them open a new page  with this result? (I'm not asking you to write code, I want to understand it from the point of view of logic)

Answer (score 0):

Well you would basically create a state for your search string and results.
Then you would fetch results based on your search string and store the results in your result state.
Then check if your results has some value in it and render it.

To show an individual result on new screen, you create a new screen and navigate to the new screen with the id of the clicked result as your params. then you can use the id from the params and fetch the individual result and display it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).